# PHP preg_match to allow only numbers,spaces '+' and '-'

Tags: php, regex, string, validation, preg-match

I need to check to see if a variable contains anything OTHER than  0-9 and the "-" and the "+" character and the " "(space).

The preg_match I have written does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

$var="+91 9766554433";

if(preg_match('/[0-9 +\-]/i', $var))
 echo $var;
?>
```

Comment: why have you decided that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add a `*` as a quantifier to the whole character class and add [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to the start and end of the regex: `^` and `$` means to match only lines containing nothing but the inner regex from from start to end of line. Also, the `i` modifier is unnecessary since there is no need for case-insensitivity in this regex.

This should do the work.

```
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9 +-]*$/', $var)){
     //variable contains char not allowed 
}else{
     //variable only contains allowed chars
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't have to escape `+` and as `-` is the last char in the group, you don't have to escape it either.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's in a group and therefore not interpreted as a qualifier, I think.

Comment: Note that this is true for empty strings as well (because of the star). If you require at least **one** character, use `+`.

Answer (score 2):

Just negate the character class:

```
if ( preg_match('/[^0-9 +-]/', $var) )
    echo $var;
```

or add anchors and quantifier:

```
if ( preg_match('/^[0-9 +-]+$/', $var) )
    echo $var;
```

The case insensitive modifier is not mandatory in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to test your regex to match your criteria and then on the left panel, you'll find code generator, which will generate code for PHP, Python, and Javascript.

```
$re = "/^[\\d\\s\\+\\-]+$/i"; 
$str = "+91 9766554433"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

You can take a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/xY6xD8/3).

Comment: `/[^\d +-]+/` works

Answer (score 0):

Try see if this works. I haven't gotten around to test it beforehand, so I apologize if it doesn't work.

```
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]+.-.+." ".*$/', $var)){
     //variable contains char not allowed 
}else{
 //variable only contains allowed chars
}
```